# python 3 encode string to ru symbols

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this string:

```
"[{\"href\": \"http://www.nord-remont.ru/remont_holodilnikov\", \"index\": \"0\", \"txt\": \"\\u0420\\u0435\\u043c\\u043e\\u043d\\u0442 \\u0445\\u043e\\u043b\\u043e\\u0434\\u0438\\u043b\\u044c\\u043d\\u0438\\u043a\\u043e\\u0432 \\u0432 \\u0415\\u043a\\u0430\\u0442\\u0435\\u0440\\u0438\\u043d\\u0431\\u0443\\u0440\\u0433\\u0435 \\u0418\\u043d\\u0434\\u0435\\u0437\\u0438\\u0442, \\u0410\\u0442\\u043b\\u0430\\u043d\\u0442, \\u0421\\u0430\\u043c\\u0441\\u0443\\u043d\\u0433 ...\"}, {\"href\": \"http://holodilnik96.ru/\", \"index\": \"1\", \"txt\": \"\\u0420\\u0435\\u043c\\u043e\\u043d\\u0442 \\u0445\\u043e\\u043b\\u043e\\u0434\\u0438\\u043b\\u044c\\u043d\\u0438\\u043a\\u043e\\u0432 \\u043d\\u0430 \\u0434\\u043e\\u043c\\u0443\"}, {\"href\": \"http://iceberg-ekb.ru/\", \"index\": \"2\", \"txt\": \"\\u0420\\u0435\\u043c\\u043e\\u043d\\u0442 \\u0445\\u043e\\u043b\\u043e\\u0434\\u0438\\u043b\\u044c\\u043d\\u0438\\u043a\\u043e\\u0432 \\u043d\\u0430 \\u0434\\u043e\\u043c\\u0443 \\u0432 \\u0415\\u043a\\u0430\\u0442\\u0435\\u0440\\u0438\\u043d\\u0431\\u0443\\u0440\\u0433\\u0435\"}, {\"href\": \"http://ekathomemaster.ru/\", \"index\": \"3\", \"txt\": \"\\u0420\\u0435\\u043c\\u043e\\u043d\\u0442 \\u0445\\u043e\\u043b\\u043e\\u0434\\u0438\\u043b\\u044c\\u043d\\u0438\\u043a\\u043e\\u0432 \\u043d\\u0430 \\u0434\\u043e\\u043c\\u0443 \\u0432 \\u0415\\u043a\\u0430\\u0442\\u0435\\u0440\\u0438\\u043d\\u0431\\u0443\\u0440\\u0433\\u0435. \\u041d\\u0435\\u0434\\u043e\\u0440\\u043e\\u0433\\u043e.\"}, {\"href\": \"http://www.ekaterinburg.holmaster.ru/\", \"index\": \"4\", \"txt\": \"\\u0420\\u0435\\u043c\\u043e\\u043d\\u0442 \\u0445\\u043e\\u043b\\u043e\\u0434\\u0438\\u043b\\u044c\\u043d\\u0438\\u043a\\u043e\\u0432 \\u043d\\u0430 \\u0434\\u043e\\u043c\\u0443 \\u0432 \\u0415\\u043a\\u0430\\u0442\\u0435\\u0440\\u0438\\u043d\\u0431\\u0443\\u0440\\u0433\\u0435.\"}, {\"href\": \"https://holodilnik66.ru/\", \"index\": \"5\", \"txt\": \"\\u0420\\u0435\\u043c\\u043e\\u043d\\u0442 \\u0445\\u043e\\u043b\\u043e\\u0434\\u0438\\u043b\\u044c\\u043d\\u0438\\u043a\\u043e\\u0432 \\u043d\\u0430 \\u0434\\u043e\\u043c\\u0443 \\u0432 \\u0415\\u043a\\u0430\\u0442\\u0435\\u0440\\u0438\\u043d\\u0431\\u0443\\u0440\\u0433\\u0435\"}, {\"href\": \"http://rembt96.ru/remont-holodilnikov-ekaterinburg\", \"index\": \"6\", \"txt\": \"\\u0420\\u0435\\u043c\\u043e\\u043d\\u0442 \\u0445\\u043e\\u043b\\u043e\\u0434\\u0438\\u043b\\u044c\\u043d\\u0438\\u043a\\u043e\\u0432 \\u0446\\u0435\\u043d\\u044b \\u0432 \\u0415\\u043a\\u0430\\u0442\\u0435\\u0440\\u0438\\u043d\\u0431\\u0443\\u0440\\u0433\\u0435 - \\u0422\\u0435\\u0445\\u0446\\u0435\\u043d\\u0442\\u0440 \\u041f\\u041e\\u041b\\u042e\\u0421\"}, {\"href\": \"http://www.holodilnyj-centr-ekaterinburg.ru/\", \"index\": \"7\", \"txt\": \"\\u0420\\u0435\\u043c\\u043e\\u043d\\u0442 \\u0445\\u043e\\u043b\\u043e\\u0434\\u0438\\u043b\\u044c\\u043d\\u0438\\u043a\\u043e\\u0432 \\u0432 \\u0415\\u043a\\u0430\\u0442\\u0435\\u0440\\u0438\\u043d\\u0431\\u0443\\u0440\\u0433\\u0435. \\u041d\\u0410 \\u0414\\u041e\\u041c\\u0423!\"}, {\"href\": \"http://remhol66.ru/\", \"index\": \"8\", \"txt\": \"\\u0420\\u0435\\u043c\\u043e\\u043d\\u0442 \\u0445\\u043e\\u043b\\u043e\\u0434\\u0438\\u043b\\u044c\\u043d\\u0438\\u043a\\u043e\\u0432 \\u043d\\u0430 \\u0434\\u043e\\u043c\\u0443\"}, {\"href\": \"http://holodprof.ru/\", \"index\": \"9\", \"txt\": \"\\u0425\\u043e\\u043b\\u043e\\u0434\\u041f\\u0440\\u043e\\u0444\\u0438 | \\u0420\\u0435\\u043c\\u043e\\u043d\\u0442 \\u0445\\u043e\\u043b\\u043e\\u0434\\u0438\\u043b\\u044c\\u043d\\u0438\\u043a\\u043e\\u0432 \\u043d\\u0430 \\u0434\\u043e\\u043c\\u0443 \\u0441 \\u0433\\u0430\\u0440\\u0430\\u043d\\u0442\\u0438\\u0435\\u0439 \\u0434\\u043e 12 ...\"}]"
```

What do I do to display russian symbols?
I tried `.encode('utf8')` and `.decode('utf8')` But didn't work

UPDATE:
I have a flask view function similar to this:

```
@app.route("/send", methods=['POST'])
def send_form():
    key =  request.form['key']
    result = dosomething(key)
    return jsonify(result)
```

Comment: This appears to be a JSON string; did you try passing it to `json.loads()` first? Also, you really didn't need to post the whole thing, just a reproducible sample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a `json` string. Not sure why it isn't displaying russian characters in the raw, but if you do

```
import json
s = <your long string>
obj = json.loads(s)
print(obj)
```

you'll get the correct display.

```
[{'href': 'http://www.nord-remont.ru/remont_holodilnikov',
  'index': '0',
  'txt': 'Ремонт холодильников в Екатеринбурге Индезит, Атлант, Самсунг ...'},
 {'href': 'http://holodilnik96.ru/',
  'index': '1',
  'txt': 'Ремонт холодильников на дому'},
 {'href': 'http://iceberg-ekb.ru/',
  'index': '2',
  'txt': 'Ремонт холодильников на дому в Екатеринбурге'},
 {'href': 'http://ekathomemaster.ru/',
  'index': '3',
  'txt': 'Ремонт холодильников на дому в Екатеринбурге. Недорого.'},
 {'href': 'http://www.ekaterinburg.holmaster.ru/',
  'index': '4',
  'txt': 'Ремонт холодильников на дому в Екатеринбурге.'},
 {'href': 'https://holodilnik66.ru/',
  'index': '5',
  'txt': 'Ремонт холодильников на дому в Екатеринбурге'},
 {'href': 'http://rembt96.ru/remont-holodilnikov-ekaterinburg',
  'index': '6',
  'txt': 'Ремонт холодильников цены в Екатеринбурге - Техцентр ПОЛЮС'},
 {'href': 'http://www.holodilnyj-centr-ekaterinburg.ru/',
  'index': '7',
  'txt': 'Ремонт холодильников в Екатеринбурге. НА ДОМУ!'},
 {'href': 'http://remhol66.ru/',
  'index': '8',
  'txt': 'Ремонт холодильников на дому'},
 {'href': 'http://holodprof.ru/',
  'index': '9',
  'txt': 'ХолодПрофи | Ремонт холодильников на дому с гарантией до 12 ...'}]
```

To get the russian-character json back, do `json.dumps(obj, ensure_ascii=False)`.

Comment: What does this do `jsonify(json.loads(result))`? It turns a `json` into a `json`? That doesn't seem right. Do `return json.loads(result, ensure_ascii=False)` instead.

Comment: TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'ensure_ascii'

Comment: What version of python is this?

Comment: python --version
Python 3.6.0

Comment: Ah balls, sorry. Got a bit confused. ignore the comments. Why are you taking a json, converting it into a string and then recovering it back into a json?!

Comment: initially it was something like this `return jsonify(result)` and then i just tried many things to get ru symbols, and may be got a little confused

Comment: So result is a string? Or a list?

Comment: Result is alist , and I changed back to `return jsonify(result)`

Comment: Instead do `json.dumps(result, ensure_ascii=False)`